# Is there a way to correct exposure on photos in a panorama taken without AE lock on?

Tags: exposure, panorama

I made a stupid mistake on some of my pano's I shot this past weekend, I forgot to hold AE-lock. Now I've got about three photos that I can't use due to difference in exposure on them.

Is there a way to fix this or will I have to play with the exposure until I get the closest match?

All photos were taken in RAW which should help a bit. Some only have a slight change and others are affected more.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessarily a mistake not to lock exposure when shooting panoramas, see this question:

- [Which parameters to lock between images for a panorama?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24185/which-parameters-to-lock-between-images-for-a-panorama)

The way to deal with this problem is to use a program that can automatically blend exposures. Recent(ish) versions (CS4 and above) will blend exposures seamlessly between frames. I've not used it but the free software [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) can apparently adjust exposures for you as well.

Matching exposure is not a difficult task for a computer, especially when it has already aligned the images.

Comment: I used the pano function in CS5 which gave the above results. After I read your response I checked again and then I saw in the bottom it says that exposure only works in 32bit. I converted the to 32 bit and it worked on the first one. I'll try later on the second one because 32bit chows a lot of memory. Thanks