# Is there free software to automatically search for photographs that can be stitched together to form a panorama?

Tags: panorama, software-recommendation, image-stitching

I'm looking for a free solution to automatically detect photographs that can be stitched together. A [paid-for solution already exists](http://www.autopano.net/) - naturally, I wonder if there is any open-source or freeware alternative out there.

I'm not actually looking for software that will *perform* the stitching; I'm quite happy to delegate to something like Microsoft ICE for that. I just want to speed up my workflow by having panorama-worthy photos in my folders be detected and suggested. Of course, a program that stitches as well would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ Auto Awesome does this.
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3113884?hl=en

It also recognizes a series of action shots, similar portraits, HDR, and has a few other trickles.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches to solving this problem:

1. Searching overlapping images. (i.e. look at the content of images.)
2. Using metadata (time between shots, further information).

I would suggest that the second method can deliver results almost as good but much easier.

I tend to shoot my images using AE and AF lock (on Nikon) which could be found in the exif data, although I cannot find it right now.

Comment: The second method would be very useful to narrow down the search for the first method, and easy enough to write into a shell script, but wouldn't be good enough for me to use in general as I tend to shoot multiple shots of the same subject in succession when waiting for movement (either action, or traffic) and when trying to combat camera shake. And I never use AE lock for panoramas, as explained in this answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24185/which-parameters-to-lock-between-images-for-a-panorama